# Append URL Creating Individual Blog Entry Page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, blogs

I have a simple blog application that I put together with PHP and MySQL (entries are housed there). I have a blog located on some url www.url.com/blog.php but where "all" blog entries are shown but that each one must have it's own URL when you click on it resulting in `www.url.com/blog.php?postID=1`, `www.url.com/blog.php?postID=2`, `www.url.com/blog.php?postID=3`, `www.url.com/blog.php?postID=so on`. **How do I append these postID on URL? How do I create these URLs after the question mark '?'**

So my blog looks like...

```
#FORM shown like, a PHP script insert the entry into MySQL database
name: ___________
Date: ___________
Blog entry:______
_________________ SUBMIT

# All blog entries are shown  here where PHP script select * from blog_table

BlogID  Author  Date  Entry
1       john    1-1-1 Something
2       dave    1-2-1 Something else
.
.
.
```

But each of these blogID must have append the url so that so that when you click on `1` should have it's own link

```
BlogID 1 = www.url.com/blog.php?postID=1
BlogID 2 = www.url.com/blog.php?postID=2
BlogID 3 = www.url.com/blog.php?postID=3
```

How would you guys do this? Advise. Thanks.

Comment: The same way you create any other link. The stuff after the `?` is just a variable that is passed to your PHP script. In your PHP script, you will have access to the `$_GET['postID']` variable, which will be whatever the number at the end of your string is. Use that to grab the proper entry from your database.

Comment: @JustinWood i use $_POST on my blog entry page. Do I have to change that to $_GET to access a variable after the ?

Comment: Yes. Any variables on the query string like that is a `get` variable.

Comment: @JustinWood  can I keep my $_POST form and somehow get the variable on my autoincremented blogID from the blog table and assign it with $_GET['blogID'][i] something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blog.php file, put in this code:

```
<a href="http://www.url.com/blog.php?id=1">Blog 1</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.url.com/blog.php?id=2">Blog 2</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.url.com/blog.php?id=3">Blog 3</a><br/>

<?php

$blogid = $_GET['id'];

//Pull the blog from the database
$query = "SELECT Entry FROM blog_table WHERE BlogID='$blogid'";
// Perform the query . . . 


echo "Here is the blog entry for blog $blogid";
// Display the results of the query . . . 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the blog ID stored as a variable just echo it into the url

$blogId = my_function_to_get_blogid();

echo 'www.url.com/blog.php?postID=' . $blogId;